# Android - SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: The user 10125 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers

Tags: android

My Android App I used & ran in 2013/2014 using Android 4.4 (API level 19) worked fine.

I'm upgrading and migrating to the latest version Android 13 (API level 30+).

When I run the App on Android Studio:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vivifyd.ViViFYdActivity, PID: 7472
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vivifyd.ViViFYdActivity/com.vivifyd.ViViFYdActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: The user 10125 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: The user 10125 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getImeiForSlot(ITelephony.java:11511)
    at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getImei(TelephonyManager.java:2049)
    at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getImei(TelephonyManager.java:2004)
    at com.vivifyd.ViViFYdActivity.onCreate(ViViFYdActivity.java:140)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I saw this: "How do we get IMEI higher than android 10":

https://support.google.com/work/android/thread/171536268/how-do-we-get-imei-higher-than-android-10?hl=en

On my "AndroidManifest.xml" I added this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CERT_INSTALL" />
```

Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: That link is about an MDM environment and `CERT_INSTALL` seems to be a MDM policy option, not an app permission. You should read the official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids and then change the code of your app that is executed on Android 10+.

Comment: No, CERT_INSTALL can not be used in Android apps at all.

Comment: Sorry I find this all a bit too 'Terse'. Can you point a more 'Dummies' location.

Comment: The "dummy explanation" is: You can not get the IMEI on regular phones.