# IMEI Android ISSUE

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, system, android-source

**Problem**: I'm trying to get the IMEI number from a device using an Android app that I installed as a system-privileged app. However, I'm getting a security exception and the app crashes whenever I try to access the IMEI number.

**STEPS TAKEN:**

- created an app in Android Studio
- Got cert platform.p8 and platform.x509.pem
- Genrated Keystore file using Keytool
- Used this keystore to Sign my Build in build.gradle file and genrated the build
- AOSP(HACKY WAY I GUESS)
- installed the genrated build into /system/priv-app/{App}/{App}.apk
- reboot my phone and got my app installed as system app
- but when i run the app it crashes and Log says Security exception occured

Any Help will be appreciated
[image]

Comment: You may have to provide some code for someone to follow your specific problem. A description of the error message is normally less useful than the actual error message. Can you capture/handle the exception and learn more about the state of things?

Comment: I think the i have specified the clear problem is to fetch imei by making android system app as the exception its security manage by android system polices.state i am not allowed to used this function even by making the system app

Comment: @ARCHER - Any progress with your IMEI  issue? I'm trying to migrate an App from: "My Android App I used & ran in 2013/2014 using Android 4.4 (API level 19) worked fine & was deployed. I'm upgrading and migrating to the latest version Android 13 (API level 30+)." - I propose to migrate to Kotlin after running in Java. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76532222/android-securityexception-getimeiforslot-the-user-10125-does-not-meet-the-re) TIA

Comment: @NOTiFY Yeah the issue was resolved from rom manufacturer side what they did was the nstered the imei no to Settings global strings which can be accessed in my application. In simple terms it was done By AOSP related things. I didn’t do much

Answer (score 0):

```
        class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
       lateinit var button: Button
       lateinit var textView: TextView
       private lateinit var IMEINumber: String
       private val REQUEST_CODE = 101
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
          title = "KotlinApp"
          textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
          button = findViewById(R.id.button)
          button.setOnClickListener {
             val telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as
             TelephonyManager
             if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity,
             Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE), REQUEST_CODE)
                return@setOnClickListener
             }  
             IMEINumber = telephonyManager.deviceId
             textView.text = IMEINumber
          }
       }
       override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String?>,
       grantResults: IntArray) {
          when (requestCode) {
             REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.q11">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: thanks for the code but the code is only works for less Android 11 versions,I am making the app which works from android 11 to latest .i.e System app which should have previleged prermissions to get imei